# RewardedVideoAdListener Methods - Admob

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services, interstitial

I am trying to understand the RewardedVideoAdListener. I have setup the Admob to show the rewarded video Ads and it is showing the video Ads perfectly.

### Reference

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAd

### Question

1. During the life cycle of the Ad, I could see only the following methods are called and not the onRewarded() method

   onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() 
   onRewardedVideoAdOpened() 
   onRewardedVideoAdClosed()

2.The Ad has a button to Install the APP like the CPI type of Ads. The user completely see the video but not installed the App, In this case he will not rewarded ? Meaning onRewarded() method willl not be called ?

```
com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener

abstract void  
onRewarded(RewardItem reward) 

abstract void  
onRewardedVideoAdClosed() 

abstract void  
onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) 

abstract void  
onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() 

abstract void  
onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() 

abstract void  
onRewardedVideoAdOpened() 

abstract void  
onRewardedVideoStarted()
```

Comment: From my experience with In-App purchases, some accounts are not eligible for purchase. Same might be in here. Maybe your account is not elligible for reward.

Comment: Or maybe you are not triggering the reward. When it is given? After install? It should write on the documentation.

Comment: I am worried that there is no Ad in Admob which is of type "Rewarded Video". Am i Right ?

Comment: AdMob should be able to provided you with an ad, int he `RewardedVideoAd` you may need to call `loadAd` to request for a rewarded video. Once complete it should be able to the interface methods (`onRewarded`) were the app should be responsible to credit the user with the reward.

Comment: I have called loadAd and Ad is shown but onRewarded is not getting called

Comment: any solution for this issue? I'm also facing the same issue sometimes.